# Set Default Sort By Name using Layout in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.4, product-sorting

I have added the listing of products on the custom page. By default sort by is Position. I have to change it to By default by Name.

```
<referenceblock class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">desc</argument>
            </action>
</referenceblock>
```

Above code is working for the direction but when I'm using setDefaultSortBy getting the error it's invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You can change default sort by from Magento Admin

> Magento Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog ->
>   Storefront -> Product Listing Sort by -> change it "Product Name" ->
>   Save Config

[image]

Comment: I know about that but I have to change only by Layout for custom products list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling a product collection's addAttributeToSort method for each ordering.

**Format:**
$ProductCollectionObject->addAttributeToSort('attribute_code', 'sort_order')

For example, wherever you see in a template, $_category->getProductCollection() or $_product->getCollection() you can then add either addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc') or addAttributeToSort('name', 'desc').

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your attribute(name) 'Used for Sorting in Product Listing' to Yes
2. Just add this block in referenceBlock

> ```
>             <action method="setSortBy">
>                 <argument name="attribute" xsi:type="string">name</argument>
>             </action>
> ```